# Script or command to replace default parameters in /etc/user on AIX

Tags: scripting, aix

I wanted to change the parameters settings in `/etc/security/user` file in AIX OS using a script. This is the sample user file.

```
default:   
        admin = false  
        login = true  
        su = true  
        daemon = true  
        rlogin = true  
        sugroups = ALL  
        admgroups =  
        ttys = ALL  
        auth1 = SYSTEM  
        auth2 = NONE  
        tpath = nosak  
        umask = 022  
        expires = 0  
        SYSTEM = "compat"  
        logintimes =  
        pwdwarntime = 5  
        account_locked = false  
        loginretries = 6  
        histexpire = 0  
        histsize = 5  
        minage = 1  
        maxage = 12  
        maxexpired = 5  
        minalpha = 0  
        minother = 1  
        minlen = 8  
        mindiff = 0  
        maxrepeats = 2  
        dictionlist =  
        pwdchecks =
```

I would like to replace values of parameters with the values below:

```
pwdwarntime = 5  
loginretries = 6  
histsize = 5  
minage = 1  
maxage = 4  
maxexpired = 5  
minalpha = 2  
minother = 1  
minlen = 8  
mindiff = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `chsec` command to do this.

`chsec -f /etc/security/user -s default pwdwarntime=5 loginretries=6`

`man chsec` for full details.